# Expiry Headers for static resources in Java Webapps

Tags: java, web-applications, jakarta-ee

is there a way to configure `Expires` headers for static resources in a Java Webapplication without having to use a servlet/controller to do the job? The reason is, that we have a bunch of static CSS, Images, and JavaScript files that will only rarely change (if at all).

Of course I could just write a Controller for those resources (and I probably will, if there is no alternative), but since this is a recurring problem I wonder if there might already be a solution out there.

PS: Since we use the Spring framework anyway, a solution from there is ok too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes do it using [Filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html), configure a filter that will intercept each static resources's request and in response modify header.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. If I have to code this, I will probably use this. But I was looking more for something without coding. It seems to me like re-inventing the wheel..

Comment: Well there are some server which some how provide this by just [configuration](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html) , but its not exactly reinventing..in your case